# Android Gmail Sender from mail error

Tags: android

```
            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("myGmail@gmail.com", "myPassWord");
            try {
                sender.sendMail("hello admin",
                        "welcome!",
                        "user13141", // <- not working!
                        "to";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
```

GMailSender.java

```
public class MailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new com.example.ddm.JSSEProvider());
    }

    public MailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }

}
```

In my GMail:

```
from: myGmail@gmail.com  
subject: hello admin  
content: welcome!
```

I want to change "myGmail@gmail.com" to "user1341".

```
from: user1341
subject: hello admin  
content: welcome!
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GMailSender.sendMail()` takes a `String sender` as an [InternetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html):

> This class represents an Internet email address using the syntax of [RFC822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt). Typical address syntax is of the form "user@host.domain" or "Personal Name ".

**Thus, your `sender` "user1341" is invalid and is ignored.**

To fix your issue, use a valid `InternetAddress` which means to give it a `sender` that follows the RFC and is of the form `user@host.domain`.

Comment: Maybe Gmail is preventing the sender from changing it's email then, I don't know. I just knew quickly that your sender was invalid.